# Copy file when the user create a folder

Tags: php, file-io, directory, file-manager, create-directory

I want to make a 'create.php' file that when the user introduces a folder name into a basic form , this file make the new folder with this name and, at the same time, copy into this folder a file ('index.php') from other folder:

Basic form:

```
<form action="create.php" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="foldername" id="foldername"></input><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Create"></input>
</form>
```

And  'create.php' file:

```
<?php
 ini_set( "display_errors", 0);
 $dir = './' .$_POST["foldername"];
 $result=mkdir($dir, 0777);
 if ($result == 1) {
    copy('index.php', $dir);
 } else {
    echo "<script>alert('ERROR');</script>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting a specific error?  Also, you should sanitize the user input so that they can back there way up through the file system and get at files they shouldn't be able to get at.

Comment: In fact, this problem is derived from other problem: im making a simple filemanager in php and i cant browse the subdirectories from the $path folder so i thought a solution that was make a universal 'index.php' and when the user creates a folder this file is copied to this new folder, but the code that i put there doesnt copy this file, create the folder but doesnt copy the file.